# How to interpret this rj45 tester double blink

Tags: networking, ethernet, rj-45

I have some cheap rj45 tester and wanted to test my newly installed rj45 cord. And because the most of cord is underfloor (there is some risk this was damages during renovation) I wanted to make sure how to interpret this double blink.

Damage or for some reason - I am not good at manual jobs - I connected the ending wrong.

- on the remote: 2 and 3 blinking at the same time
  [image]
- on the main: 2 blinking slightly stronger
  [image]

So far I researched it is T-568B:

This is the female wall rj45:

[image]

I made an attempt on the another end as in the picture
[image]

Comment: You're untwisting too much wire.  Review best practices for connecting twisted pair cable to RJ45 connectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a short between wires 2 and 3.

Comment: found guy interpreting this on yt https://youtu.be/y3DmOPrmBio?t=144

Comment: can I interpret it as endings of the cord are connected ok but there is something screwed up on the way or I can not exclude the case of screwing up with pinning the ends?

Comment: @andilabs: I don't *think* you can deduce the exact location or the short, it might be in the cable run or at either end's termination.

Comment: could you spot in additionally added photos of female rj45 connection anything wrong?